# How can I designate a combination of two checkbox fields as a unique value for counting in a query?

Tags: ms-access-2016

Access 2016

In my form/table "Ceramic Catalog", I have a field "Temper" in which records can have multiple values. These values are "Shell (Coarse)", "Shell (Fine)", "Grit", and "Grog". I want "Shell (Coarse) and Grit" and other combinations of the values to become *unique* values that are counted so that my query generates this:

Record 1: Shell (Coarse) and Grit

Record 2: Shell (Coarse)

Record 3: Grit

Record 4: Shell (Fine) and Grog

Record 5: Shell (Coarse) and Grit

COUNTS:

Shell (Coarse) and Grit: 2

Shell (Coarse): 1

Grit: 1

Shell (Fine) and Grog: 1

I believe the way I'm currently trying to run the query is generating it so that records with multiple values are being counted multiple times. I only want a record counted once.

I apologize if I'm not doing a great job explaining this. I'm entirely new to Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try this aggregating query:

```
Select Temper, Count(*) As Counts
From [Ceramic Catalog]
Group By Temper
```